# Writing output of query to .xlsx from a stored procedure in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am needing to replace my current process of creating procedures in SQL Developer to write the output of a query into a CSV, with code that will output a .xlsx file instead. I've done some cursory research on the topic, but answers seem way over my head.

I've tried to mimic solutions I found on google/stack overflow to no avail.

EXAMPLE OF CSV PROCEDURE:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE EXAMPLE_FILE_CSV AS
  CURSOR c_data IS
                       ‘QUERY HERE’;

  v_file  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(location     => 'EXTRACT_DIR',
                           filename     => 'EXAMPLE_FILE.CSV',
                           open_mode    => 'w',
                           max_linesize => 32767);
  FOR cur_rec IN c_data LOOP
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file,
                      cur_rec.COL1   || ',' ||
                      cur_rec.COL2    || ',' ||
                      cur_rec.COL3      || ',' ||
                      cur_rec.COL4      || ',' ||
                      cur_rec.COL5 || ',' ||
                      cur_rec.COL6    ;
  END LOOP;
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);
    RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: i'm sure there are a few of these out there https://renenyffenegger.ch/Oracle/Libraries/xlsx-writer.html

Comment: The solution will depend on which 3rd party program you use.  Which program you use depends on the size of the data.  The open source options work fine for creating fancy Excel files, but only if the number of rows is relatively small.  If you have to export a hundred thousand rows then only commercial software can handle that size.

Answer (score 0):

Th example code you provided uses UTL_FILE, which can only access/create files on the Oracle server.

Since you mention you are currently manually running queries then copy/past(?) into Excel, the UTL_FILE option wont help you.

Now, to put this query data into a local/client side files this approach might get you started - write a script that runs in SQLPlus/SQLDeveloper and output a *CSV* file, using the following as a template/example. XLSX format is trickier.

myscript.sql:

```
SET LINES 2000
SET PAGES 0
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SPOOL the_output.csv
SELECT col1 || ',' ||
       col2 || ',' ||
       col3 || ',' ||
       col4 || ',' ||
       col5 || ',' ||
       col6
FROM the_table
WHERE ...;
SPOOL OFF
```

Another option you have is to use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE as follows:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE EXAMPLE_FILE_CSV AS
  CURSOR c_data IS
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4,
       col5,
       col6
FROM the_table
WHERE ...;
    BEGIN
      FOR cur_rec IN c_data LOOP
        DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
                          cur_rec.COL1   || ',' ||
                          cur_rec.COL2    || ',' ||
                          cur_rec.COL3      || ',' ||
                          cur_rec.COL4      || ',' ||
                          cur_rec.COL5 || ',' ||
                          cur_rec.COL6    ;
      END LOOP;
    END;
    /
```

To invoke this you would do the following in a caller script:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
SET LINES 2000
SET TRIMSPOOL OFF
SPOOL the_output.csv
EXEC EXAMPLE_FILE_CSV;
SPOOL OFF;
```

Comment: SQLDev has a CSV output mode for scripts, you can just write the SQL as is and get the results out in csv

Answer (score 0):

the mentioned requirement is feasible by using 'xls' coding via  plsql.
in simple words- we use plsql to generate xls coding as per need and have it as a excel file.

the basic xls coding to generate an excel file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">cell data</Data></Cell> 
    .........
   </Row>
   ........
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
......
</Workbook>
```

the approach is to generate the coding with the values from the database accordingly.

example:

consider the table:

```
ROLL_NO NAME            AGE
01      student no 1    15
```

following plsql code will generate the excel sheet for this table record

```
declare
cursor c1 is select * from student_tbl;
l_xls_code varchar2(4000);
begin
l_xls_code:= CHR(60)||'?xml version='||CHR(34)||'1.0'||CHR(34)||'?'||CHR(62)||CHR(12)||
CHR(60)||'Workbook xmlns='||CHR(34)||'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'||CHR(34)||'
 xmlns:o='||CHR(34)||'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'||CHR(34)||'
 xmlns:x='||CHR(34)||'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'||CHR(34)||'
 xmlns:ss='||CHR(34)||'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'||CHR(34)||'
 xmlns:html='||CHR(34)||'http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'||CHR(34)|| CHR(62) ||
 CHR(60)||'Worksheet ss:Name='||CHR(34)||'Student Data'||CHR(34)|| CHR(62) ||
  CHR(60)||'Table'|| CHR(62)||
   CHR(60)||'Row'|| CHR(62)|| 
    CHR(60)||'Cell'|| CHR(62)||CHR(60)||'Data ss:Type='||CHR(34)||'String'||CHR(34)|| CHR(62)||'Roll No.'||CHR(60)||'/Data'|| CHR(62)|| CHR(60)||'/Cell'|| CHR(62) ||
    CHR(60)||'Cell'|| CHR(62)||CHR(60)||'Data ss:Type='||CHR(34)||'String'||CHR(34)|| CHR(62)||'Name'||CHR(60)||'/Data'|| CHR(62)||CHR(60)||'/Cell'|| CHR(62) ||
    CHR(60)||'Cell'|| CHR(62)||CHR(60)||'Data ss:Type='||CHR(34)||'String'||CHR(34)|| CHR(62)||'Age'||CHR(60)||'/Data'|| CHR(62)||CHR(60)||'/Cell'||CHR(62) ||
   CHR(60) ||'/Row'|| CHR(62);

-- dynamically having values from the table into the excel sheet
For rec in c1
loop
l_xls_code:= l_xls_code||
 CHR(60)||'Row'|| CHR(62)|| 
    CHR(60)||'Cell'|| CHR(62)||CHR(60)||'Data ss:Type='||CHR(34)||'String'||CHR(34)|| CHR(62)||rec.roll_no||CHR(60)||'/Data'|| CHR(62)|| CHR(60)||'/Cell'|| CHR(62) ||
    CHR(60)||'Cell'|| CHR(62)||CHR(60)||'Data ss:Type='||CHR(34)||'String'||CHR(34)|| CHR(62)||rec.name||CHR(60)||'/Data'|| CHR(62)||CHR(60)||'/Cell'|| CHR(62) ||
    CHR(60)||'Cell'|| CHR(62)||CHR(60)||'Data ss:Type='||CHR(34)||'String'||CHR(34)|| CHR(62)||rec.age||CHR(60)||'/Data'|| CHR(62)||CHR(60)||'/Cell'||CHR(62) ||
   CHR(60) ||'/Row'|| CHR(62);
end loop;



l_xls_code:= l_xls_code|| CHR(60)||'/Table'||CHR(62) ||
 CHR(60)||'/Worksheet'||CHR(62)|| 
CHR(60)||'/Workbook'||CHR(62);


dbms_output.put_line(l_xls_code);

end;
```

the above code displays the output. that will be the xml coding that can be stored in the file with '.xls' format
this will be opened via excel sheet only

this file will be having the data from the table.
in the above mentioned example, the data is fetched by cursor and is used to generate the code dynamically.
in the similar way, styles like font, cell color, cell width, etc... can be dynamically defined via plsql and can be coded into the file as per required.

usually this variable would be a clob, lob variable (as in real time scenarios this xml coding would be quite large) that can be sent as an attachment, or to create a file in server location.

similar method can be done via unix scripting - to have the xls coding generated by sql session as per required and to spool them in a file